# Which event is fired when the server is autostarted after reboot?

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2

```
// in dpr:      
if not Application.DelayInitialize or Application.Installing then
    Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMSService, MSService);

// and then:
procedure TMSService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
    //initalization code
    // timers are activated (timers control the real work)
end;
```

this is my scenario:

1) service is installed and set as autostart on server - service is running fine (it is "running" in `services.msc` and it reads/writes from db= "does the real work")

2) server is rebooted

3) after reboot service is started in `services.msc` but it does not read/write from db (="it does not the real work"...).

To make it read/write again i need to uninstall and reinstall it, stopping and starting it is not enough. I thought TMSService.ServiceStart was the correct place to code in to have the code executed on  a service autostart, but it seems not. I am missing something, this is why the question's title is "Which event is fired when the server is autostarted after reboot?".

Any hint?

Comment: Did you try logging? In the ServiceStart code, write log information to a file, for example using Log4D, and then examine the log file after a reboot.

Comment: yes i will try this with DebugView, anyway the ServiceStart is the correct event?

Comment: Yes. That event is triggered every time the service is started for any reason. You should not do your database work directly in that event, though. It needs to exit as soon as possible, as the SCM is waiting for it for exit so it can move on to other things. Have the event spawn a worker thread instead to do your actual work. Use the OnStop/Shutdown events to terminate the thread.

Comment: Also make sure your dependencies are in place. If your service relies on a DB service having started then make sure that it's marked as a dependency. That way, Windows will make sure the DB starts before your service.